# gem is very slow

Tags: ruby, rubygems

On my server searching is fast but on my local machine gem searches are slow.
Can I do something for speed up my gem searches?

Answer (score 3):

The solution from Doc Snuggles really works.

But it should be notice that your `gem` command maybe living in a gemset, that is:

```
rvm info | grep gem
```

will tell you where the `gem` script lives.

Then edit it and add the magic line before any other `require`:

```
require 'resolv-replace'
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try this:

> In gem (mine’s at /usr/local/bin/gem),
>   add this line before any other code:
>
> require 'resolv-replace'

Answer (score 0):

remove a few gems (couldn't resist).
make sure you're on the latest version.
are you running windows? [if so, 1.9.1 is slow with gem lists for some reason]
-r

Comment: looks like about your only option is to <gulp> use ruby-prof to try and track down which part of gems is taking so long and see if you can speed it up/identify the problem/patch back into rubygems.  Make sure you're using the latest version of gems.  Could also try building the latest of rubygems...
http://github.com/vvs/rubygems
GL.
-r