# Force RubyGems to use HTTP

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I've been trying to workaround the fact that `gem install` is extremely slow on a 2.9GHz Intel Core 7 MacBook Pro.

I applied solutions I found on the internet:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887704/gem-is-very-slow
http://buddingrubyist.wordpress.com/2009/02/14/how-to-speed-up-gem-installs-10x/
```

However they made no difference to me. A few posts including this one ([ruby - bundle install/update too slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343771/ruby-bundle-install-update-too-slow), first comment to user1189762's answer) says that `RubyGems` are slower when fetching from HTTPS.

This is my `.gemrc`:

```
---
gem: --no-ri --no-rdoc
benchmark: false
verbose: true
update_sources: true
sources:
- http://gems.rubyforge.org/
- http://rubygems.org/
backtrace: true
bulk_threshold: 1000
```

My `sources` are both using `http`, however if doing a verbose installation I get:

```
$ sudo gem install rack -V
Password:
GET https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET https://s3.amazonaws.com/production.s3.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
200 OK
GET https://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/rack-1.5.2.gemspec.rz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET https://s3.amazonaws.com/production.s3.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/rack-1.5.2.gemspec.rz
200 OK
Installing gem rack-1.5.2
```

All The requests are being made with `https`.

Anyway to force `http` in `gemrc`? Is that my bottleneck?

Comment: do you know taht http is insecure against of https, and using the http opens a vulnerability for specific attacks.

Comment: `https` is a bottleneck? On a 2.9Ghz machine? Are you kidding us, right?

Comment: @philpirozhkov Applying the SSL layer on my box will not be a bottleneck, but it seems to be on their side, as http is much faster no the gem repository

Comment: SSL adds ~0.5% overhead as reported by Google

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `.gemrc` is not applied because it lives in your user directory but when you execute the command with `sudo` the ownership of the execution is halted.

Either do not use sudo or use

```
$ sudo gem sources
```

to manage the sources.

Usage: gem sources [options]

```
  Options:
    -a, --add SOURCE_URI             Add source
    -l, --list                       List sources
    -r, --remove SOURCE_URI          Remove source
    -c, --clear-all                  Remove all sources (clear the cache)
    -u, --update                     Update source cache
```

The command

```
$ sudo gem sources -c
$ sudo gem sources -a http://rubygems.org/
```

should change the source list.

Please keep in mind that if you are using rvm, bundler or rbenv, it's likely you don't need `sudo` to install your gems.

Comment: I'm using the ruby package that came preinstalled on my Mac by default. Running without `sudo` will give a permission error at the end, and it'll still use https! `sudo gem sources` worked for me, seems that is not even reading the sources in my `gemrc`, even without sudo

Comment: Beautiful, this fixed my issue. Ubuntu 12.04 kept hanging on any gem install. Upon changing the gem sources it looked like it failed, however upon the next install, gem install found the correct sources fine.

Comment: It worked for me, but only after using the commands without `sudo`